# Recyclerview - CardView with Headers for cards and different cards

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, cardview

I have a `CardView` in my app and I don't to know how I can add `TextView` and headers for some cards like on the picture. I marked it with the arrows. Also I want to know how I can add different cards in a `RecyclerView` and not just the same cards.

[image]

Thanks for your answers and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: You should check SuperSlim. I believe it does what you want: https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM

Comment: you can do this by assigning these values a view type by getViewItemType(int position) for reference follow this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type